# PHP - Find the difference / subtraction between the values of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting values of two company stocks through a third party website using an API. These are output as two arrays e.g.

```
$companyA = array([0] => 100 [1] => 100.20  [2] => 103.20);
$companyB = array([0] => 99 [1] => 101.30  [2] => 105.50);
```

Each key [0],[1],[2], etc.. represents a day and is the same day for both stock dates. I would like to try and find the difference in values in the array by doing a subtraction for  each value. i.e. 100 - 99, 100.20-101.30, 103.20 - 105.50, etc...

I tried array_diff but it's not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$result = array_map(function ($firstElement, $secondElement) {
    return $firstElement - $secondElement;
}, $companyA, $companyB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this with basics:

```
<?
$companyA = array(100,100.20,103.20);
$companyB = array(99,101.30,105.50);

$newArr = array();
foreach ($companyA as $key => $value) {
    $newArr[] = ($value-$companyB[$key]);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => -1.1
    [2] => -2.3
)
```